# Importing a custom JFrame and JPanel class cannot be resolved

Tags: java, class, jframe, jpanel, importerror

I tried cleaning my project to fix this and looked up into forums and stackoverflow for a solution however I wasn't able to find an answer of why an error is showing. I'm simply importing my class into my Actual_Game class. The error is "The import FrameCreator cannot be resolved". I'm using Eclipse as my IDE.

Here's the code:
Actual_Game.java

```
import FrameCreator;//<---error here

public class Actual_Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FrameCreator local_fc = new FrameCreator();
        local_fc.CreateGameWindow();
    }
}
```

FrameCreator.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class FrameCreator extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /*      Settings      */
    /*      get screen size using the Toolkit class before setting it into height & width       */
    static Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    final String title = "Example Title";
    final static int window_height = (int)(screenSize.getHeight()*.75),
                     window_width = (int)(screenSize.getWidth()/2);
    public FrameCreator(){
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        CreateGameWindow();
    }
    public void CreateGameWindow(){
        /*    This section creates the window     */
        /*    set the title of the screen     */
        JFrame archizzleFrame = new JFrame();
        /*    sets the size of the frame     */
        archizzleFrame.setSize(window_width,window_height);
        /*    we tell what to do when user presses "X"     */
        archizzleFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        /*    sets visibility of the window     */
        archizzleFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

They are under the same folder/package as shown below.

[image: Same file directory]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't place class within the default package, this is one of the side effects. Based on the screen shots, you don't actually need the import as classes in the same package are automatically accessible - although, the default package has some queer side effects

Comment: That actually solves the problem. Thanks @MadProgrammer However, I wonder why does it do that? Is there any reason behind it?